# android, MaterialButton button color changed after adding style Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight

Tags: android, material-components-android, materialbutton

having a MaterialButton, with style:

```
<style name="InstallButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/InstallButtonThemeOverlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="InstallButtonThemeOverlay">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/btn_color</item>
    </style>
```

and color is blue:

```
<color name="btn_color">#E6188FFF</color>
```

It has been working, but when the aar is used in a app which does not using the material them the app crashes,

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
```

Have to adding the 
`android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"` to the button,
the app does not crash anymore, but the color changed to purple

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
                    android:id="@id/btn"
                    style="@style/InstallButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    app:cornerRadius="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:text="Install Now"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

How to keep the color as defined in the style?

Comment: You **have to use** a Material Components Theme in your app.

Answer (score 2):

adding the `"backgroundTint"` made it work, not sure if there is better way:

```
<style name="AdInstallButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/InstallButtonThemeOverlay</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/btn_color</item>
    </style>
```